# How to Unpack a Parent object into a child object using Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to unpack a parent object using automapper and create a new child object with it:

parent:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child Child {get;set;}
}


public class Child
{
    //stuff
}
```

First attempt at mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Parent, Child>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Parent.Child);
```

Error message:

```
    Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.
```

That makes sense so I tried to resolve it myself:

```
.BeforeMap((src, dest) =>
{
    dest = new Child();
});
```

This didn't work for the same reason, even though I would argue that I am resolving the object.

So, How do I resolve the child object, so that I can create it using automapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the same object reference as the result:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Parent, Child>()
    .ConvertUsing(par => par.Child);
```

Here you're telling AutoMapper that you know how to do the entire mapping, which in this case just means returning the inner `Child` property.

Note that the following is true if you go this route:

```
Parent p = new Parent();

Child c = Mapper.Map<Child>(p);

object.ReferenceEquals(parent.Child, c); // true
```

If you wanted to copy the entire `Child` instance into a brand new instance, you could set up a mapping from `Child` → `Child` and then call `Mapper.Map` inside of the `ConvertUsing` call:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Parent, Child>()
    .ConvertUsing(par => Mapper.Map<Child>(par.Child));

Mapper.CreateMap<Child, Child>();

Parent p = new Parent
{
    Child = new Child { Name = "Kid" }
};

var ch = Mapper.Map<Child>(p);

object.ReferenceEquals(parent.Child, ch); // false
```